# Java, compare Strings in a list of object.s

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, string-comparison

Hello and sorry if I did not explain myself properly.
I am trying to compare if a String is within a previously created list of objects.
example:

```
List<People> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<>();
Person person1 = new Person("Marija" , "Zagreb");
Person person2 = new Person("Joan", "Barcelona");
Person person3 = new Person("Vinko" , "Zagreb");
listOfPeople.add(person1);
listOfPeople.add(person2);
listOfPeople.add(person3);
```

What I want to do is checking the city value and be able to create a message if a person appears has the same location. I can't seem to search strings of specific values within a list.

listOfPeople.contains is telling me "given object cannot contain instances of String.
Please let me know if I should extend my question.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: add src of People class and what you tried,  so we can help you better

Comment: Hey! Do you understand what the error message tells you and why? You have a list of `Person` instances and each instance has those attributes ...

Answer (score 1):

From java8, you can use stream, example bellow

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class newExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<People> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<People>();

        People People1 = new People("Marija", "Zagreb");
        People People2 = new People("Joan", "Barcelona");
        People People3 = new People("Vinko", "Zagreb");
        listOfPeople.add(People1);
        listOfPeople.add(People2);
        listOfPeople.add(People3);

        String city = "Barcelona";

        if (listOfPeople.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getCity().equals(city))) {
            // found
        }

    }
}

class People {

    String name;
    String city;

    public People(String name, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Java 8` and above, you can use this:

```
package com.Example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person1 = new Person("Marija" , "Zagreb");
        Person person2 = new Person("Joan", "Barcelona");
        Person person3 = new Person("Vinko" , "Zagreb");
        listOfPeople.add(person1);
        listOfPeople.add(person2);
        listOfPeople.add(person3);
            
        listOfPeople.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getCity().equals("Barcelona"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);          
    }
}

class Person implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -414171236169806542L;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    
    public Person(String name, String city) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", city=" + city + "]";
    }
}
```

Output:

> Person [name=Joan, city=Barcelona]